# How can I launch a new session of tmux in iTerm2 on a separate window?

Tags: tmux, session, iterm2

I would like to start a tmux session on a separate window in iTerm2. Now I'm writing my own configuration script to launch the session.

```
tmux new-session -s dev -n main -d
tmux send-keys -t dev "cd $DL" C-m
tmux split-window -h -t dev
tmux split-window -v -t dev -p 30
tmux resize-pane -x 70 -y 20
tmux attach -t dev
```

This starts a new session but the window is on the window I execute the script, not the new, separate window in iTerm2.

So I changed the first line (`tmux new-session -s dev -n main -d`) to `tmux -CC new -t dev`, but then although the session starts in a new window, it does not have the split and the resize. It seems to only open the new session in a new window and that's all.

How can I make it launched in a new window with all the initial settings including the directory change, split window, etc...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use applescript to do something like this:

```
$ cat a.bash
#!/bin/bash
osascript - "$@" <<EOF
on run argv
tell application "iTerm"
    activate
    set new_term to (create window with default profile)
    tell new_term
        tell the current session
            repeat with arg in argv
               write text arg
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
end run
EOF
```

This provides a script which can then pass arguments passed into it, into another iterm2 terminal.

For example:

```
$ ./a.bash "echo 'hello iterm2'"
```

[image: ss of iterm2 launch]

#### References

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675804/how-do-i-execute-a-command-in-an-iterm-window-from-the-command-line

Comment: Thanks but how can I take the script to the argument of the `a.bash`? `./a.bash < my_script` does not work (it only launches the window). It works if it is `./a.bash "tmux new -s dev"`, though.

Comment: @Blaszard - can you please update your question, it's not clear what exactly you want/expect to happen here then.If the last part works I'd saw your problem's solved, which I know isn't the case in your mind, but we need more to go on then.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Your command for control mode is mostly correct, but you should replace the *last* line with it, not the first line. Use this as your last line:

```bsh
tmux -CC attach -t dev
```

By the way, your first two lines can be combined into one:

```bsh
tmux new-session -s dev -n main -d "cd $DL; $SHELL"
```

Comment: Note that you might want to quote `$DL`, depending on what you know about its value.